# Jupyter Notebook starting with Netbeans

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Recently Jupyter Notebook has been loading up Netbeans editor at the start instead of going straight to Notebook? I am unsure why this is happening?

Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.5.0
ipykernel        : 6.16.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 8.3.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.7.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.2
nbclient         : 0.6.8
nbconvert        : 7.0.0
nbformat         : 5.5.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : 5.4.2
traitlets        : 5.9.0

when I type

> jupyter notebook

I get netbeans html page

[image]